# Using pandas read_xml to generate a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, xpath

I am trying to write an XML document (shown below) into a pandas dataframe.  I am using `df = pd.read_xml(doc.xml, xpath='//Generator)'` but i keep getting an error saying `ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.`I have also tried adding the xmlns=url and xmlns:xsi=url to `namespace=` parameters with no luck. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My XML document looks like this:

````
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="url"?>
<IMODocument docID="document" xmlns="url" xmlns:xsi="url" xsi:schemaLocation="url">
    <IMODocHeader>
        <DocTitle>
            Generators Output and Capability Report
        </DocTitle>
        <DocRevision>
            4
        </DocRevision>
        <DocConfidentiality>
            <DocConfClass>
                PUB
            </DocConfClass>
        </DocConfidentiality>
        <CreatedAt>
            2021-08-18T10:15:50
        </CreatedAt>
    </IMODocHeader>
    <IMODocBody>
        <Date>
            2021-08-18
        </Date>
        <Generators> //Portion i'm trying to write into a data frame
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
            <Generator>
            </Generator>
        </Generators> // ----------------end-------------------
    </IMODocBody>
</IMODocument>```
````

Comment: You can use xmltodict package instead: https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/. It loads the XML as dictionary and then you can use pd.json_normalize() to convert it to dataframe.

Comment: How should the DF look like?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with namespaces. If you try changing your xpath expression from `=` to `contains()`, like this:

```
df = pd.read_xml(doc.xml, xpath='//*[contains(name(),"Generator")]')
```

it seems to work, at least for me with your sample xml.

Not sure why this happens; a bug?

Comment: This is weird... It's not formatting how I expected it too.  I kind of thought this was going to be as easy as pandas read_csv is or read_excel but this seems much more complex

Comment: @ZacharyMcArthur Indeed; `read_xml()` is brand new, so that may be part of the issue.